# Sitecore_list_index on CDs

Tags: content-search, content-delivery

What exactly is the sitecore_list_index used for? Can it be deleted or can its crawling strategy be set to manual on CDs without affecting any other part of Sitecore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sitecore_list_index contains  the list of contacts and segmented lists that are used by the List Manager, the Email Experience Manager and the Experience Profile.

More information you can find here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/search_index_descriptions

On this link https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server you can see that you need to disable List Manager index on a content delivery server.